# SSH connection refused port 22

Tags: centos, ssh

I have a server running centos 6.4 with whm. Last night the cpu and ram overloaded randomly and it crashed out. Shortly after this we booted into rescue mode and began running fsck checks as the server failed to come back online. After this the server came back online however the ssh is now refusing connections and whm has not come back online any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do the connections to SSH return 'Connection Refused' or they simply time out?

Comment: connection refused

Comment: Can you paste the `netstat -lpn` output? Maybe sshd is just crashing as soon as it starts. Check `/var/log/messages` for details.

Answer (score 1):

If the ssh daemon does not start automatically on boot then from OVH's rescue console mount the local root partition for example to /mnt

This could be something like

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Modify `sda1` according to your partitioning scheme.

Then run the following command to temporarily enable ssh on startup.

```
echo "/etc/init.d/sshd start" >> /mnt/etc/rc.local
```

Then do a reboot.

After booting, it should start the sshd after loading all other services.

If that works, then you revert what you did with /etc/rc.local (delete that line you added while on rescue mode)

And run

```
chkconfig sshd on
```

to properly enable sshd on startup.

It's weird though that after a server crash ssh won't start.
Did fsck made a lot of changes to the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Is your sshd daemon is up and running if yes make sure iptables should not be blocking it. Also disable SELINUX setenforce 0 and check if your ssh works or not?

```
 service sshd status
```

It should be running

```
 setenforce 0
```

Comment: I'm currently unable to do anything when the server starts so I have it in ovh's rescue pro. setenforce is set to 0. It hasn't worked since the memory and cpu spike last night.

Comment: how about your iptables, stop iptables , restart sshd daemon and then reboot your server in normal mode and see .

Comment: The server isnt started thats the problem rescue mode only lets you mount the disks.  I've checked the ip table config and its fine its not blocking port 22 so im not sure what to do.

Comment: what error it gives you when you try to start it?

Comment: We're not getting errors its just not letting us ssh in so i think its an ovh issue but im not sure.